# how to make a highlighted cell in UITableView to de-highlighted?

Tags: iphone

I have a TableView with lots of content in the cell; if the user taps the cell it highlights the cell in gray color, and also a popup comes out on the selected cell: popup is a subview with some controls. If the popup close button is tapped i want to de-highlighted the selected cell. How is it possible to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

`[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];`

Comment: i know this code and it is only applicable in tableview diselectrowatindexpath method,i put this code in my _closebutton click,it shows indexpath undeclared.so how can i put this code in my close button click.i want the deselection occurs only when the user tap the close button of the popup as i mentioned in my question.any help?Thanks